# how would I use Javascript, html and css to produce the running tiger effect seen in run4tigers website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wasn't sure if this question has already been asked before but I was wondering how you produce the interactive dotted text and the running tiger animation you see in the middle of the run4tiger website?
http://run4tiger.com/
Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: They are using a canvas with some JavaScript to animate it but it's really difficult to share the code. The best solution is to use the developper tool and to extract what you want from the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) elements to achieve this.
The canvas will catch the mouse over events and then react accordingly.
The loading tiger screen was drawn using [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG).

Comment: Thanks a lot natus for the help, hopefully I'll be able to produce something like that eventually!

Comment: Good luck! :) I'm sure you will be able too :)